# Action cam - Bad video color in some cases - reason?

Tags: video-quality, lighting, action-cam

if you compare these two screenshots which were made from a video (DJI Osmo Action 4) with the same settings, you see the quality on the one is pretty nice, but the trees in the other one look pretty bright with bad quality.
What could be the reason, that the trees look so bad in the other case? It is because it was too light and should I have used some ND filter or something?

Color was set to "normal, 10bit", light is set to "auto", recording was 4K 25 frames.

[image: good]
[image: bad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second image isn't exposed as well as the first image. If the camera was on Auto mode, it will continuously try to adjust the exposure and colour settings to compensate to get the best image recorded. But sometimes it will fail to correctly guess the right settings.

All cameras have a lower dynamic range than your eyes, so they have to make some compromises through adjustments to colour, exposure, white balance etc to create a pleasing image.

Check [the manual on pages 13-14](https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/DJI_Osmo_Action_4/UM/20230906/DJI_Osmo_Action_4_User_Manual_v1.2_en.pdf) for how to manually adjust exposure and white balance. You will get more consistency, but this might be less useful on an "action" camera, where you're often shooting for motion and excitement rather than precise accuracy (e.g. if you set the exposure in an outdoor position, then go into a tunnel, the camera will not adjust the exposure and the image will appear too dark).

Comment: Ok thanks, that explains it. So would it basically be better to make all settings manually to find a compromise that fits for all different landscapes?
(Currently I use only 2 profiles, one for dark indoor videos, so everything is set to manually, and one for outdoor where almost all the settings are set to auto)